# Why after watching rewared video ad the app restarts?

Tags: android, android-activity

I display an ad in the begging of my activity, the app is published and everything works fine but on some phones after the user watches the rewarded video ad and then closing it the app restarts (I am not sure if it is actually restarting but it leads him back to the main first activity)

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_1);
        MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-6995305968327976~6090393454");
        mad = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        mad.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
        mad.loadAd("ca-app-pub-6995305968327976/4158310785",new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

And this is the `onRewardedVideoAdLoaded()` method:

```
@Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
        LinearLayout everything;
        everything = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.everything);
        everything.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(!QuizActivity.this.isFinishing()){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder =  new AlertDialog.Builder(QuizActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("...");
            builder.setMessage("...");
            builder.setCancelable(false);

            builder.setPositiveButton("...", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if(mad.isLoaded()){
                        mad.show();
                    }
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("..", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            GifImageView load;
            load = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.load);
            load.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: On which phones is it restarting?

Comment: jellybean 5+ is the android version.

Comment: Jellybean is 2.3 and 5+ are over Lollipop. So, where exactly you are having problem?

Comment: Ооps sorry my mistake just the phone is with Lollipop then.

Comment: Just for the record: Jellybean is 4.1, 4.2, 4.3  More or less.

Comment: It's an HTC if that matters m7